# Update google sheet from android using service acount?

Tags: android, google-sheets

I would need help with recording data with an Android app to Google Sheets using a service account.
I read hundreds of threads that are using mostly deprecated Google credentials which doesn’t work.
Can someone help or have an idea how to write a line (data) in Google Sheets?

**Update:**

In my gradle I added this:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:19.0.0'
implementation 'pub.devrel:easypermissions:0.3.0'
implementation('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.23.0') {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
}
implementation('com.google.apis:google-api-services-sheets:v4-rev581-1.25.0') {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
}
implementation 'com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-jetty:1.23.0'
```

And here is my class for read from google sheet as seen in googles example:

```
public class GoogleSheetHelper {
private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "Google Sheets API Java Quickstart";
private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
private static final String TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH = "tokens";
private static final List<String> SCOPES = Collections.singletonList(SheetsScopes.SPREADSHEETS_READONLY);
private static final String CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH = "/credentials.json";

private static Credential getCredentials(final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT, Context context) throws IOException {
    // Load client secrets.
    //InputStream in = GoogleSheetHelper.class.getResourceAsStream(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
    InputStream in = context.getAssets().open("credentials.json");;
    if (in == null) {
        throw new FileNotFoundException("Resource not found: " + CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
    }
    GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));
    File tokenFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +
            File.separator + TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH);
    if (!tokenFolder.exists()) {
        boolean success = tokenFolder.mkdirs();
        if( !success ){
            throw new RuntimeException("File Error in writing new folder");
        }
    }
    FileDataStoreFactory f = new FileDataStoreFactory(tokenFolder);
    // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
    GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
            HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
            .setDataStoreFactory(f)
            .setAccessType("offline")
            .build();
    //LocalServerReceiver receiver = new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setPort(8888).build();
    return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
}
public static void napravi(Context context) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    // Build a new authorized API client service.
    //final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
    final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = new com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport();
    final String spreadsheetId = "1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms";
    final String range = "Class Data!A2:E";
    Sheets service = new Sheets.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, getCredentials(HTTP_TRANSPORT, context))
            .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
            .build();
    ValueRange response = service.spreadsheets().values()
            .get(spreadsheetId, range)
            .execute();
    List<List<Object>> values = response.getValues();
    if (values == null || values.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("No data found.");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Name, Major");
        for (List row : values) {
            System.out.printf("%s, %s\n", row.get(0), row.get(4));
        }
    }
}
```

And because I was getting NetworkOnMainThreadException in MainActivity i call this in Thread:

```
new Thread(() -> {
        try {
            GoogleSheetHelper.napravi(getApplicationContext());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        runOnUiThread(()->{
            // OnPostExecute stuff here
        });
    }).start();
```

But i am now getting this exception:

```
2020-11-26 06:50:06.447 30966-31002/hr.krkec.orchestrabarcodeapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-3
Process: hr.krkec.orchestrabarcodeapp, PID: 30966
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava/awt/Desktop;
    at com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.browse(AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.java:129)
    at com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.onAuthorization(AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.java:113)
    at com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.authorize(AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.java:81)
    at hr.krkec.orchestrabarcodeapp.Helpers.GoogleSheetHelper.getCredentials(GoogleSheetHelper.java:75)
    at hr.krkec.orchestrabarcodeapp.Helpers.GoogleSheetHelper.napravi(GoogleSheetHelper.java:89)
    at hr.krkec.orchestrabarcodeapp.MainActivity.lambda$onCreate$1$MainActivity(MainActivity.java:112)
    at hr.krkec.orchestrabarcodeapp.-$$Lambda$MainActivity$dMONIKNVXAJxtq31-j2RI7GKpKk.run(Unknown Source:2)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "java.awt.Desktop" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/hr.krkec.orchestrabarcodeapp-DmJDmyzrsZ1Fz0c3Wtg9xg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/hr.krkec.orchestrabarcodeapp-DmJDmyzrsZ1Fz0c3Wtg9xg==/lib/x86, /data/app/hr.krkec.orchestrabarcodeapp-DmJDmyzrsZ1Fz0c3Wtg9xg==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:93)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    at com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.browse(AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.java:129) 
    at com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.onAuthorization(AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.java:113) 
    at com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.authorize(AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.java:81) 
    at hr.krkec.orchestrabarcodeapp.Helpers.GoogleSheetHelper.getCredentials(GoogleSheetHelper.java:75) 
    at hr.krkec.orchestrabarcodeapp.Helpers.GoogleSheetHelper.napravi(GoogleSheetHelper.java:89) 
    at hr.krkec.orchestrabarcodeapp.MainActivity.lambda$onCreate$1$MainActivity(MainActivity.java:112) 
    at hr.krkec.orchestrabarcodeapp.-$$Lambda$MainActivity$dMONIKNVXAJxtq31-j2RI7GKpKk.run(Unknown Source:2) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a way to use Google Sheets API in your android app through Android SDK, this might help you.

**Setting-up Google Workspace APIs for Android**
https://developers.google.com/gsuite/guides/android

*Pre-requisites:*

- Must have a Google account
- Android Studio SDK 1.2 or later
- Android SDK packages for API 23 or later

Prepare the project:

In your Android project, include a **build.gradle** file with dependencies such as these:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'
    compile 'pub.devrel:easypermissions:0.3.0'
    compile('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.23.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }
    compile('com.google.apis:google-api-services-<API>-<VERSION>') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }
}
```

Be sure to replace the **API** and **VERSION** with the Google Workspace API and version. For example, the Google Sheets API would have the target compile '**com.google.apis:google-api-services-sheets:v4-rev581-1.25.0**'

Once the service is authenticated, executing the API call is the same as shown in any of the Google Workspace Java quickstarts.

Summary for Java Quickstart Procedure:

1. Turn on the Google Sheets API
2. Prepare the project
3. Setup the sample
4. Run the sample

For more details regarding the Java Quickstart please refer here:
https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/java

Answer (score 0):

You need to supply your own Browser to AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp

```
return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, receiver, new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.Browser() {
    @Override
    public void browse(String url) throws IOException {
        // open browser here on the url
    }
}).authorize("user");
```

Answer (score 0):

I've gone through many learning curves including reading this posting. I finally figured this problem out and described my finding: [use google sign in to connect to google sheets api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74512198/use-google-sign-in-to-connect-to-google-sheets-api/75575824#75575824)

The key is to follow the example from https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/android/signin to create a GoogleSignInAccount obj. Then, create a GoogleAccountCredential obj. to be used as the credential to Sheets.Builder.

Code skeleton

```
GoogleSignInAccount signedInAccount = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this);
Account account = signedInAccount.getAccount();
GoogleAccountCredential credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(
                                context,
                                Collections.singleton("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"));
credential.setSelectedAccount(account);

Sheets service =
    new Sheets.Builder(httpTransport, GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance(), credential)
            .setApplicationName("Google Sheets API")
            .build();
```

*NOTE*: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets" is the SCOPE for the sheets API.

I hope that saves the reader time in the future. What I learned along this journey is that this authentication method changes. Pay attention to the date. Let me know when my finding is no longer valid.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/33968444)

Comment: Updated per suggestion from Bö macht Blau.