# use google sign in to connect to google sheets api

Tags: android, kotlin, google-api, google-signin, google-sheets-api

I've been trying to write an android app with access to a google sheet. Unfortunately, I need to be able to write to the sheet as well as read so I can't use an api-key. I've used the google sheets api quick start: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/java

The problem I've encountered is that whenever I get far enough that asks me to login to google, this shows up:
[image]

I then followed the instructions for how to login to my app using google sign in. This is my MainActivity for it:

```
package com.example.frcscout22sheets

import Home
import android.content.ContentValues.TAG
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import com.example.frcscout22sheets.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInClient
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions
import com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Scope
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.SheetsScopes


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private lateinit var mGoogleSignInClient: GoogleSignInClient

    companion object {
        val instance = MainActivity()
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        val gso = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken("975626648989-jf3cl536froqejdc741ai934ek540ovv.apps.googleusercontent.com")
            .requestScopes(Scope(SheetsScopes.SPREADSHEETS))
            .requestServerAuthCode("975626648989-jf3cl536froqejdc741ai934ek540ovv.apps.googleusercontent.com")
            .requestEmail()
            .build()

        mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);

        val dataFragment = Data()
        val allianceSelectionFragment = AllianceSelection()
        val homeFragment = Home()

        val signin = findViewById<SignInButton>(R.id.sign_in_button)

        setCurrentFragment(homeFragment)

        signin.setOnClickListener {
            signIn()
        }

        binding.bottomNavigationView.setOnItemSelectedListener {
            when (it.itemId) {
                R.id.data -> setCurrentFragment(dataFragment)
                R.id.alliance_selection -> setCurrentFragment(allianceSelectionFragment)
                R.id.home -> setCurrentFragment(homeFragment)
            }
            true
        }
    }

    private fun setCurrentFragment(fragment: Fragment) =
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().apply {
            replace(R.id.flFragment, fragment)
            commit()
        }

    private fun signIn() {
        val signInIntent: Intent = mGoogleSignInClient.signInIntent
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, 1)
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            // The Task returned from this call is always completed, no need to attach
            // a listener.
            val task: Task<GoogleSignInAccount> = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data)
            handleSignInResult(task)
        }
    }

    private fun handleSignInResult(completedTask: Task<GoogleSignInAccount>) {
        try {
            val account = completedTask.getResult(ApiException::class.java)

            // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
        } catch (e: ApiException) {
            // The ApiException status code indicates the detailed failure reason.
            // Please refer to the GoogleSignInStatusCodes class reference for more information.
            Log.w(TAG, "signInResult:failed code=" + e.statusCode)
        }
    }
}
```

however, it's unclear to me where to go from here. When using the quickstart instructions, I would get the credentials from the .json that I downloaded from the cloud console and use that to get the credential which was then used to build the service in a different class:

```
private val service = Sheets.Builder(
        HTTPTRANSPORT,
        jsonfactory,
        getCredentials(context, HTTPTRANSPORT)
```

How do I use the google sign in to access the sheets api? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google documents definitely don't make this easy for Android app development. I went through the same pain of trying to get this to work, one tiny process at a time with countless hours spent on searching, reading, and tweaking. I reached the very same blocker you described. Finally, I figured out and read my sheet data. The key as you already know is how to create that credential object implementing com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestInitializer. The magic class to use is **GoogleAccountCredential**!

The best example for reference is https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/android/signin I started out understanding SignInActivityWithDrive, which doesn't show how you use google client API after signing in. Then, I found the usage of GoogleAccountCredential in RestApiActivity. I didn't have any luck getting RestApiActivity working due to some illegal argument exception I got. As I've updated SignInActivityWithDrive to try to get Sheets working, I just applied the usage of GoogleAccountCredential there. Bam, Sheets just started to work within minutes.

In short, here is the overall code flow:

1. Get a valid GoogleSignInAccount based on the example

```
GoogleSignInAccount signedInAccount = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this);
```

2. Get an Account obj. from it.

```
Account account = signedInAccount.getAccount();
```

3. Create the dreadful credential obj. from it.

```
GoogleAccountCredential credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(
                                context,
                                Collections.singleton("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"));
                        credential.setSelectedAccount(account);
```

*NOTE*: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets" is the SCOPE for the sheets API.

4. Apply this credential obj. into the typical sheet example code you've been using.

```
                        Sheets service =
                            new Sheets.Builder(httpTransport, GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance(), credential)
                                    .setApplicationName("Google Sheets API")
                                    .build();
                        ValueRange response = service.spreadsheets().values()
                                .get(spreadsheetId, range)
                                .execute();
                        List<List<Object>> values = response.getValues();
```

That is it. Good luck on your journey.